# try to avoid multiple instances of eclipse editor opening same file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-rcp, rcp

I registered a custom editor with eclipse extension point "org.eclipse.ui.editors" as follows.

```
<extension
     point="org.eclipse.ui.editors">
     <editor 
            class="com.xxx.designer.scxml.ui.ScxmlDiagramEditor" 
            id="com.xxx.designer.scxml.ui.ScxmlDiagramEditor"
            extensions="scdiagram"
            name="SCXML Editor">
</editor>
```

It works fine, this editor is associated with .scdiagram files. However, every time I click on one same .scdiagram file, it opens a new instance for me instead of highlighting the opened file. Any idea on this?

Thanks,

Jie

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is make your `IEditorInput` return true for the same files. You could implement this by comparing the canonical names of your files. Don't forget to also override the hashCode() method. [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java)

See Lars Vogel's excellent tutorial [Eclipse Editor Plugin Tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEditors/article.html) for more details on using Editors.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how my question was resolved eventually. It's related to [Graphiti](http://www.eclipse.org/graphiti/) and solution is also tied to the framework.

Since I subclassed Graphiti's diagram editor, all I need to do is to set org.eclipse.graphiti.ui.editor.DiagramEditorMatchingStrategy as the editor's matching strategy in plugin.xml.